# Continuously Reordering A List By Dragging

Tags: codenameone

I looked into drag and drop and found that the drop method of Container shuffles the containers components.

That brought me to ask myself: wouldn't it be nice if drop happened continously while keeping on dragging.

So I did just that - only it yields strange results. Apparently it gets into a state where the dragged component is not painted anymore and the dragFinished method of the dragged component is not called when releasing the pointer.

Please help me understanding what is going wrong there.

Here is the code:

```
public class FormContinuousDrop extends Form {
    private class LabelDraggable extends Label {
        int pressedX = 0;

        public LabelDraggable(String aCaption) {
            super(aCaption);
            setDraggable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
            super.pointerPressed(x, y);
            pressedX = x;
        }

        @Override
        public void pointerDragged(int x, int y) {
            Log.p("LabelDraggable.pointerDragged(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            super.pointerDragged(pressedX, y);
            { // Here is where the "list" is shuffled whilst remaining dragging
                if (isDragActivated() && !getAnimationManager().isAnimating()) {
                    ContainerDropTarget containerDropTarget = (ContainerDropTarget) getParent();
                    containerDropTarget.drop(this, pressedX, getDraggedy());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void dragFinished(int x, int y) {
            Log.p("LabelDraggable.dragFinished(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            super.dragFinished(x, y);
        }
    }

    private class ContainerDropTarget extends Container {
        public ContainerDropTarget() {
            super(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            setDropTarget(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentAt(int x, int y) {
            boolean edt = Display.getInstance().isEdt();
            Log.p("ContainerDropTarget.getComponentAt(" + x + ", " + y + ") - EDT: " + String.valueOf(edt));
            return super.getComponentAt(x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public void drop(Component dragged, int x, int y) {
            Log.p("ContainerDropTarget.drop(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            super.drop(dragged, x, y);
        }
    }

    public FormContinuousDrop() {
        setTitle("FormContinuousDrop");
        setScrollable(false);
        Container containerContent = getContentPane();
        containerContent.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        containerContent.add(new SpanLabel("Simple Drag And Drop example where drop is done continously whilst dragging"));
        ContainerDropTarget containerDropTarget = new ContainerDropTarget();
        for (int tally = 0; tally < 20; tally++) {
            containerDropTarget.add(new LabelDraggable("draggable " + (tally + 1)));
        }
        containerContent.add(containerDropTarget);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok - I found that the method `com.codename1.ui.Container.removeComponentImplNoAnimationSafety(Component)` which is called by `com.codename1.ui.Container.removeComponent(Component)` which is called by `com.codename1.ui.Container.drop(Component, int, int)` sets the Form.dragged to null

Comment: When the drop method is modified to restore the `Form.dragged` this works almost nicely. 
There remains a flicker for which I don't know what causes that.
The final call to `drop`from `com.codename1.ui.Component.dragFinishedImpl(int, int)` should be prevented because this may shuffle the list again when the pointer moves off screen whilst dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I tried to do cannot be done for now and for those reasons:

- The method `com.codename1.ui.Container.drop(Component, int, int)` indirectly causes the variable `Form.dragged` to be set to zero, which in turn causes the drag to be interrupted - see issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1992
- If the method `com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.isAnimating()` returns false this doesn't mean no animation is in progress - see issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1993
- `com.codename1.ui.Component.dragFinishedImpl(int, int)` scrolls the drop target container using screen coordinates which often leads to strange results with scrollable containers - see issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1994

It would be difficult to find workarounds for the mentioned things because often only private or package private access exists and Codename One does not support overshadowing of classes.

On the other hand, I do not feel familiar enough with Codename One to make the appropriate changes myself and post a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some animation pending then the remove/add might create an animation and defer things like the removal/addition to prevent collision between multiple animations. You should always check the actual status of the component before adding/removing.

Comment: Ok, I swap components only when `!getAnimationManager().isAnimating()` - what could I check in addition?

Comment: I get this clear flashing effect when components are removed and then to be inserted again, as the method `drop` does. Probably there is no good reason why no method `com.codename1.ui.Container.moveComponent(Component, int)` exists, except that it just does not exist, right? Such a method should be save and all it needed to do was move the component in the Container.components, right?

Comment: I tried it with a new method `com.codename1.ui.Container.moveComponent(Component, int)` - with the same flashing effect in the simulator, which I still don't understand.

Comment: I traced `paint` and `setY` of the other component being moved - not the one being dragged. That looks all very reasonable. Maybe I need to know more about the painting when dragging. The dragged component is not drawn with the others not being dragged. Where is this distinction done?

Comment: Historically add/remove were always synchronous so there was no need for a move that doesn't animate which I assume is what you mean by that? The question is what is triggering the animate/repaint here which is something that's hard to guess without a rather complex debug session as it's hard to hit a breakpoint while dragging....

Comment: I have had a hard debug session ;-) and probably known now what's going on. I'll prove it and come back with the outcome.

Comment: Ok - `com.codename1.ui.Container.MorphAnimation.updateState()` keeps getting called even if `MorphAnimation.finished` is true. That is because `com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.updateAnimations()` calls it when `com.codename1.ui.animations.ComponentAnimation.isInProgress()` returns true AND when it returns false. Therefore one cannot assume that no animation is going on when `com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.isAnimating()` returns false. Is it a bug? I get a clean animation when calling `com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.flush()`.

Comment: That might be relate to functionality like tickering or URLImage loading.